# Responsive button design

Tags: css, responsive-design

So what I'm trying to achieve is make this div with Buff text inside of it fill out the area here is a picture of how it looks like right now
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSGKB.png but when I resize the browser https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI5jY.png

```
<div style="overflow: auto;width: 100%; min-height: 41px; max-height: 100%; position: relative;">
        <div style="background-color: #80DE57; color: white; float: right; text-align: center;width:  10%;height: 8%%;max-height:  100%;">BUFF</div>

        <p style="margin: 0 1% 0 1%;word-break: break-all ">
    d   4444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444                                
        </p>
</div>
```

EDIT:
I also want the height to always fill out this div

Comment: Try to apply a pixel in width instead of percentage.
eg: `width: 50px`. To make it responsive you can do adjustments by @media breakpoints and apply specific width.

Answer (score 0):

Your Buff div has a width of 10%, so naturally it will shrink as the screen size decreases. Give it a fixed width, but use em units not px ones so that the size will adjust according to the text size the user is using. Eg:

```
width: 5em;   // (choose a suitable value to give a sensible width
```

Comment: This helped with width how about height though?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to preserve your width:10% than you should give your button a minimum width:

```
min-width:50px;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msxwokex/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the width property from the button. Adjust the spacing around the button through padding. Let the button grow based on text inside it.

Answer (score 0):

[Updated Code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXwaRz)

I have done it using `display: table` and `display: table-cell`

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
        <p class="leftCnt" >
    d   4444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444
        </p>
  <div class="rightCnt" >BUFF</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%; 
  min-height: 41px;
  max-height: 100%; 
  position: relative;
  display: table
}
.leftCnt {
  word-break: break-all; 
  display: table-cell
}
.rightCnt {
  background-color: #80DE57; 
  color: white; 
  text-align: center;
  min-width:  50px;
  width: 10%; /*Add this*/
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align:middle
}
```

Comment: This layout is messed up with just few letters not full lines the button on right takes 80% of the width http://i.imgur.com/y90TTmK.png